# NodeJS: callback not a function

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I've checked the other questions but none form an answer to mine. In other words: no answer works.

I've got two modules: app and logic. App passes a callback to logic, which logic then calls. However I get the error "cb is not a function". That's it, no more information.

This is the function in app.js that poses the callback:

```
app.get('/assignments/open/:student', function (request, response) {
  var callback = function(mail, jobtitle) {
    response.status(200).json(logic.getOpenAssignments(request.params.student));
  }

  logic.examine(request, callback);
});
```

This is the function in logic.js that calls the callback:

```
examine: function (request, cb) {
        var options = {
            host: 'graph.microsoft.com',
            path: '/v1.0/me',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': request.get('Authorization')
            }
        };

        var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
                mail = chunk['mail'];
                jobtitle = chunk["jobTitle"];
                cb(mail, jobtitle);
            })
          });
    },
```

Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Following code doesn't work:

```
examine: function (request, cb) {
        var options = {
            host: 'graph.microsoft.com',
            path: '/v1.0/me',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': request.get('Authorization')
            }
        };

        var req = http.get(options, res => {
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
                mail = chunk['mail'];
                jobtitle = chunk["jobTitle"];
                cb(mail, jobtitle);
            })
          });
    },
```

Following code also doesn't work, does this mean the scope is not the problem?

```
examine: function (request, cb) {
        var options = {
            host: 'graph.microsoft.com',
            path: '/v1.0/me',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': request.get('Authorization')
            }
        };

        cb('hehe', 'hoho');
    },
```

Comment: If I'm not guessing it wrong, `cb` is not defined in the scope of the `http.get`'s callback function. You should either use arrow functions to pass the scope, or pass the function `cb` in `http.get`'s callback function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES6, try to use arrow function to pass the scope to `http.get`'s callback function:

```
var req = http.get(options, res => {
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
        mail = chunk['mail'];
        jobtitle = chunk["jobTitle"];
        cb(mail, jobtitle);
    })
});
```

Or you could also pass `cb` to your callback function :

```
var req = http.get(options, function(res, cb) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk, cb) {
        chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
        mail = chunk['mail'];
        jobtitle = chunk["jobTitle"];
        cb(mail, jobtitle);
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, it would work. The best solution is to use arrow functions because you pass the whole scope to your function, but if you want to access `cb`, the only way is to pass it manually into the callback

Comment: No i meant the second code snippet, passing cb to http.get callback.Will  Logic.examine send cb it received as arguments to https.get?Wouldn't cb in http.get be undefined?

Comment: I'm afraid both methods don't work... I'll edit my question with my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is, you are not waiting for data chunk to process. Try the following snippet. Added a way to convert http.get to promises(very common) and this avoids passing all the messy callbacks.

```
//put this somewhere inside where examine is located.
logic.httpGet = options => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(options, res => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = ''; 
      res.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
      res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
};

//convert your route like this
app.get('/assignments/open/:student', function (request, response) {
  cont options = {
        host: 'graph.microsoft.com',
        path: '/v1.0/me',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': request.get('Authorization')
        }
    };
  return logic
          .httpGet(options)
          .then((data)=>{
             const data =JSON.parse(data);
             //i don't see where you use the processed data but do whatever you want below here
           repsonse.status(200).json(logic.getOpenAssignments(request.params.student))
          })
})
```